# Is there a word that describes internal self harming?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

Is there a word where you look for things that trigger you, not to desensitise yourself but to hurt yourself? So, emotional, mental or psychological self harm. Is there a word for it?

Comment: So, psychological self harm?

Comment: Yes, emotional, mental or psychological self harm. Is there a word for it?

Comment: I'd say just that. BTW, Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: About [single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Comment: [self-flagellation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-flagellation) might be nearer, and context would clarify that it is psychological rather than physical. [Self-criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-criticism) is a recognised psychiatric term, as is depression. People who are severely depressed tend to be trapped in negative thinking and believing themselves as to be unworthy.

Comment: But it's important to know whether pleasure is derived from this self-conflicting of emotional pain.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of self-harmful behavior is [autosadism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autosadism). It is the desire to inflict harm on oneself, either physical or psychological, and may or may not be sexual in nature.

Comment: masochism is the first term that comes to mind.

Comment: I think masochism has more specifically sexual connotations.

Comment: Sadism does too. They both have "sexual" connotations. People are sadistic and masochistic due to severe neuroses. See Freud and Lacan. :)

Comment: @Lambie, masochism means the desire to receive pain. It does not indicate that the source of the pain be oneself; indeed, I would say that the majority of masochists seek someone else to inflict the pain on them.

Comment: @masochists are people who get off on pain inflicted on them. I don't believe there is a term for mental versus physical masochism. Masochists seek to feel pain regardless of who inflicts it.